# Suppose $a_n \rightarrow a$, and $|{a}| < 1$. Prove $(a_{n}) ^ n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was shown the exact proof twice by my professor, but I still cannot remember for my life. It ended with proving that $|a_n|$ < 1, and so it is well known that this raised to the n power converges to 0.

Comment: Let $\epsilon=(1-|a|)/2>0$. Then by definition of limit there is $N>0$ such that $|a_n-a|<(1-|a|)/2$. Hence $|a_n|\leq |a_n-a|+|a|<(1+|a|)/2<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\epsilon>0$ we have that $|a-a_n|<\epsilon$ eventually. First pick $|a|<\delta<1$ and put $\epsilon := \delta-|a|$ which is greater then $0$. Then

$$|a_n|\leq |a_n-a+a|\leq |a_n-a|+|a|<\epsilon+|a|=\delta$$

eventually. And so $a_n$ becomes a sequence inside $(-\delta,\delta)$ for $0<\delta<1$ and thus $a_n^n\to 0$. That's because $a_n^n\in(-\delta^n,\delta^n)$.

**Side note:** the condition $|a_n|<1$ is not enough for $a_n^n$ to converg to $0$ as $a_n=1-1/n$ example shows (thanks to @Redundant Aunt) with $a_n^n\to e^{-1}$.

Comment: Small detail: $|a_n|<1$ doesn't imply $a_n^n\to 0$, take $a_n=1-1/n^2$ for example. So you would have to chose $\epsilon=(1-|a|)/2$.

Comment: @RedundantAunt Indeed, fixed.